# R fill matrix based on element names from data frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

If I have data that may be modelled as so:

```
a1 <- c("bob","bill",0.2)
a2 <- c("bob", "bert", 0.1)
a3 <- c("bill", "bert", 0.1)

my.df <- as.data.frame(rbind(a1, a2, a3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

colnames(my.df) <- c("name_1", "name_2", "value")
row.names(my.df) <- NULL

my.names <- unique(as.character(c(my.df$name_1, my.df$name_2)))

my.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = length(my.names), ncol = length(my.names))

row.names(my.matrix) <- my.names

colnames(my.matrix) <- my.names
```

How may I fill `my.matrix` using the values from `my.df`. The first two columns in `my.df` describe the coordinates of `my.matrix` to fill?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can coerce the first two columns of `my.df` into an index matrix, and index-assign `my.matrix` with the remaining column of `my.df` as the RHS:

```
my.matrix[as.matrix(my.df[c('name_1','name_2')])] <- as.double(my.df$value);
my.matrix;
##      bob bill bert
## bob    0  0.2  0.1
## bill   0  0.0  0.1
## bert   0  0.0  0.0
```

I also coerced the RHS to a double, since I assumed you want to preserve the type of `my.matrix`.

Comment: Great thanks! This worked best with the real data and I was able to easily adapt it to fill the other half of the matrix.

Comment: I have a follow up question, is it possible when the data is missing to set the cell as empty instead of 0?

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution using a `for` loop:

```
my.df$value <- as.numeric(my.df$value)
for (i in 1:nrow(my.df)) {
   my.matrix[rownames(my.matrix) == my.df$name_1[i], 
             colnames(my.matrix) == my.df$name_2[i]] <- my.df$value[i]
}
```